# Bash get string between 2 6-digit numbers

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a UTF-8-BOM encoded text file full of lines of which most start with a 6-10-digit (number increases every line) and have a string behind them.

I want to get each of those "lines" (including the number) to process further in my bash script.

It'd be an easy to do by just using a for loop with `sed -n '$line\p'` but unfortunately some of those strings I need have line breaks as part of them, so I need a way of extracting the string between two 6+ digit numbers (including the first number) which mark a new line.

An example of 3 "lines":

```
123456\tA random string here
123567\t another string
this time
it goes over
multiple lines
124567\t a normal string again
```

What I need:

```
123456\tA random string here
```

,

```
123567\t another string
this time
it goes over
multiple lines
```

and

```
124567\t a normal string again
```

A few things:

- The strings are not surrounded with "" unfortunately
- All numbers the strings contain are <6 digits long, so a >=6 digit number is always the start of a new string line
- The number increases, so the number before the string is always lower than the one behind
- I'd like to convert all special characters like tabs or line breaks to `\t` or `\n`
- I need to get the byte length later in the script, a string must keep it's length

I'm still new here, so if I put this in the wrong place or if it was already answered, tell me!

Comment: Can you copy paste the sample of the file with an expected output?

Comment: As a starting point you probably want to look at doing this in `awk`.

Comment: An example would be useful!

Comment: Is you `\t` an actual tab? Do your 6 digit numbers always start out a record, or can they be found further in the record as well?

Comment: it's an actual tab

Answer (score 0):

I hope the "UTF-8-BOM encoded" is not a trap.
Here is my proposal if it is not.

```
bash-3.1$ sed -En '/^[0-9]{6,10}/!{:a;H;n;/^[0-9]{6,10}/!ba;x;s/\n/\\n/g;s/\t/\\t/g;p};/^[0-9]{6,10}/{x;s/\t/\\t/g;1!p;x;h;z;}' input.txt
```

Output for sample input (with a newline at the end):

> 123456\tA random string here
>   123567\t another string\nthis time\nit goes over\nmultiple lines
>   124567\t a normal string again

I assumed that the relevant 6-10 digits also always are at the start of a line,
otherwise it gets trickier.

Note:
The string length will increase by 1 for each newline `\n` or tabulator `\t`;
because the requested "\n" and "\t" are two characters each.